# Help with Test Class

Tags: unit-test, community, controller

When you have a trigger or a class to write unit test for, one would setup the data structure and then execute your code against the data by insert or calling the class between Test.start() and Test.end() methods.

How do I execute the code in my test method when it is based on a command button that user has to click?  Once click, the button will execute the method below:

```
public pagereference submitBriefingRequest() {
    // Get the secord being saved
    Speaker_Request__c BR = (Speaker_Request__c) std.getRecord();
    Boolean procStatus = sendSpeakerinfotoBS(BR.ID,ACTION_SUBMIT,'');
    return null;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Create an instance of the controller and call `submitBriefingRequest` from your test.

Comment: Thank you Keith.  I did that but I'm getting an error:  Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [CtrlBriefingSource].<Constructor>()

Comment: I have added these lines:  Test.startTest();
            CtrlBriefingSource controller=new CtrlBriefingSource();
            controller.submitBriefingRequest();
        Test.stopTest();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure the StandardController to pass to the constructor (assuming that is what `std` is in your code.

E.g.

```
public static testMethod void testSubmittBriefingRequest() {

    Speaker_Request__c sr = new Speaker_Request__c();
    insert sr;

    PageReference pref = Page.YourVisualforcePage;
    pref.getParameters().put('id',masterObject.id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(pref);

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(sr);

    CtrlBriefingSource cbs = new CtrlBriefingSource(sc);
    PageReference result = cbs.submitBriefingRequest();
    System.assertEquals(null, result);

}
```